# CMake - Create executable for all *.cpp file in folder

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I have this folder tree:

```
benchmark/
├─ pair/
│  ├─ benchmark_create.cpp
│  ├─ benchmark_insert.cpp
│  ├─ benchmark_remove.cpp
├─ set/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

And this is my current `CMakeLists.txt` file content:

```
add_executable(dbg_pair_creation pair/benchmark_creation)
target_link_libraries(pair_creation benchmark::benchmark)

add_executable(dbg_pair_insert pair/benchmark_insert)
target_link_libraries(pair_insert benchmark::benchmark)

add_executable(dbg_pair_remove pair/benchmark_remove)
target_link_libraries(pair_remove benchmark::benchmark)
```

There is a compacxt way to do the same and to put this executable in a folder with name `pair` that is the folder name of the source?

Comment: What have you tried? The logic seems to be trivial, like: "foreach file in a directory { create an executable for that file}".

Comment: You're missing `.cpp` at the end of your file names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a foreach loop.

```
set(benchmarks creation insert remove)
foreach (benchmark IN LISTS benchmarks)
  add_executable(dbg_pair_${benchmark} pair/benchmark_${benchmark}.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(dbg_pair_${benchmark} PRIVATE benchmark::benchmark)
  set_property(
    TARGET dbg_pair_${benchmark}
    PROPERTY RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY 
             "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dbg_pair_${benchmark}"
  )
endforeach ()
```

Then you would just need to add to the `benchmarks` list when you add a new benchmark.